# spark-submit protobuf openrtb java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, apache-spark, protocol-buffers

I have gzipped files on s3, files contain encoded Base64 string representing byte array of the protobuf message.
Proto scheme looks like:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package com.myproject.proto;
option java_outer_classname = "MyProtos";
import "openrtb.proto";

message Request {
    optional int64 timestamp = 1;
    optional com.google.openrtb.BidRequest bidRequest = 2;
    optional string otherData = 3;
}
```

When I running next spark code for flatMap function from local:

```
public static Iterator<MyProtos.Request> parseRequest(String source) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(source);
        MyProtos.Request request = MyProtos.Request.parseFrom(bytes);
        return Collections.singletonList(request).iterator();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Collections.emptyIterator();
    }
}
```

everything is ok, but when I try run this code on remote by spark-submit I got exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage.hasExtension(Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension;)Z @2: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionLite'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b600 21ac
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my case was that the app was built with protobuf 3.5.0 but Spark had 2.5.0 in the jars dir. Simple resolution was to drop the new 3.5.0 jar in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Runtime Enviroment variable `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` by default equals false.
If run spark on remote or locally in client mode, there was no such dependencies conflict problem.